# How to view the amount of active connections in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to view the amount of active connections in SQL and in Oracle, grouped by program.

To SQL I did this query and works fine:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName,
     sys.sysprocesses.hostprocess
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame, hostprocess;
```

I would like to do a query which returns the same results but in Oracle. 
I have tried some queries that I found here on StackOverflow but no helps me.

Comment: Which queries? Why didn't they help? Sounds like you're just looking for [`v$session`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of active sessions aggregated by program, you can try:

```
select COUNT(*), PROGRAM
from v$session
where status = 'ACTIVE'
  GROUP BY PROGRAM
```

On the same view, you can find much more informations, about sid, user, client, etc.; [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9.htm#REFRN30223) you find more informations.
Just for the sake of completeness, you have to consider `Gv$session` on RAC environment

Comment: Session means the same that connection means?

Comment: Same meaning; this is  what you need if you want to know who is connected, doing what, ...

Comment: Do you know how could I set the 'processes limit' of Oracle to unlimited?

Comment: I can't help with this, but you can look around in Oracle documentation; I'd try starting from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
select status, count(*) as connections from V$SESSION group by status;
```

If you need to see who is logged by their `username`, use this

```
select username,status, count(*) as connections from V$SESSION where username is not null group by status,username;
```

**OUTPUT FROM MY DATABASE**

```
+----------+---------------+
| STATUS   | CONNECTIONS   |
+----------+---------------+
| ACTIVE   | 104           |
+----------+---------------+
| INACTIVE | 284           |
+----------+---------------+
```

Here status being `ACTIVE` means `the number of session currently executing SQL`

> [V$SESSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223) here is the place to look more into it.